# httpd running as apache.apache, but logs owned by root.root?

Tags: apache-httpd

ps shows my httpd processes as

```
apache   29561 15186  0 15:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

I'm running Centos 5.3

All the log files in /var/log/httpd are owned by root.

How come?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `httpd` children run as apache, but the process that spawns them runs as root (as is necessary to bind a privileged port eg. port 80).  Look closely and you'll see an `httpd` running as root.